# Can I ask about what sort of things I should ask a luthier for?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I am taking my violin to a luthier. There's nothing *massively* wrong with it, it's a culmination of a few issues that I would like professional advice on and potentially require things like a new bridge/soundpost.

Can I ask a question about '**What should I ask my luthier about from a general maintainence perspective?**' or would that be off topic?

I think it could fall somewhere between:

- Instrument maintainence or repair (on topic); and
- shopping help — including product or music search — or buying/selling advice or recommendations (off topic)

[Relevant help page](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That's a very good question, imo! I recently had that issue with an old classical guitar, I didn't know exactly what to ask for, other than "what can you do for this old guitar"?

Comment: I don't think it matches the shopping help label at all. That rule is in place to prevent "tell me what guitar to buy" or "what bass is the best" type of questions, which yours is not. Seems ok to me.

Comment: @Lyd perfect. I wasn't completely sure, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would seem to be an appropriate question for the Music Stack Exchange. The expected responses would come from other violinists and (hopefully) luthiers. Answers to evaluate would include condition of the instrument, the manner in it's use, and possibly which luthiers to contact.